# Segmentation fault while importing ggplot in python via rpy2

Tags: python, r, rcpp, rpy2

I'm running the following commands in python:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
importr( 'ggplot2' )
```

This works fine in python-2.7.6 and rpy2-2.8.3.  However it gives the following error when run on python-2.7.8 and rpy2-2.8.5 :

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning: Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so: undefined symbol: R_ClassSymbol
warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: I'm not a python user (yet), but the practice of reporting bugs in the R world is to assume that a seg-fault is ipso facto indication of a bug and these should be reported to whatever responsible parties handle those. Bug reports to SO are not encouraged for buggy R code. This one looks like you do not have Rcpp properly installed, but the authors of your Python package _should_ be checking for that issue rather than letting it be signalled by a seg-fault. Added the [rcpp] tag so Dirk can offer any further insight.

Comment: I'm with @42 here. You probably just need to reinstall that stack of RPy2 and/or Rcpp.  On my Ubuntu box(en) your two lines of Python work without fail with Python 2.7 ...

Comment: `R_ClassSymbol` is a symbol provided by `libR.so`, so presumedly your system is somehow misconfigured in such a way that `rpy2` is not loading that shared object.

Answer (score 0):

1. rpy2 is a package which provide access to R when you are using python. So firstly make sure that you enabled R-shared libs when you compiles you R as follows:
   **./configure --prefix=* --with-x=no --enable-R-shlib=yes**
2. make sure you have specified the following environment variable before you distribute your rpy2 package:
   **export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/R/lib64/R/include**
3. Last but not least, only those packages installed when all of this requirements are satisfied can be rightly imported in python by importr. And if not, you may need to reinstall the R packages.